# Order of operations for multisampling in DirectX 10

Tags: c++, directx-10

I'm confused on the process that needs to be done for anti-aliasing in DirectX 10. I haven't done it at all before, so it may just be that I'm confused on the procedure in general.

Here's what I know so far (or think I know): you need to enable multisampling for your RasterizerState object that you use in the shader, and that the SampleDesc in the swap chain description (DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC) needs to be set to a supported value for Count (and that Quality should stay 0, since other values or hardware-specific - though I don't know what for). Between the calls to prepare for more drawing (ClearRenderTargetView and IASetInputLayout) and the call to Present, the back buffer should be downsampled (via ResolveSubresource) to an otherwise equal-sized texture. Then, (this is the part I can't find anything on) somehow present the downsampled texture.

Do I have something messed up along the way? Or am I just mistaken on the last step? I saw a few resources refer to doing the sampling resolution during one last draw to a full-screen quad with a multisampled shader texture (Texture2DMS<>), but can't figure out what that would entail, or why you would do it over the device call to just resolve it that way.

Any attempt I've made at this doesn't produce any increase in image quality.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I'm using DX11, you just use D3D10_ instead of D3D11_, thanks DeadMG.

You don't need to do any downsampling.

Find out what kind of quality modes and sample count your GPU supports. 
You said that the quality level should be 0, that is wrong. Use this to get the supported quality modes with sample counts:

```
UINT GetMSAAQuality(UINT numSamples,DXGI_FORMAT format)
    {
        UINT q=-1;
        HR(m_device->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(format,numSamples,&q));
        return q-1;
    }

    // Use it like this:
    UINT sampleCount=4; // You set this
    UINT sampleQuality=GetMSAAQuality(sampleCount,DXGI_FORMAT_CHOOSE_ONE);

    // For swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC d;
    d.SampleDesc.Count=sampleCount;
    d.SampleDesc.Quality=sampleQuality;

        // Now for all the textures that you create for your
        // render targets and also for your depth buffer
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dtex;
        dtex.SampleDesc.Quality=sampleQuality;
        dtex.SampleDesc.Count=sampleCount;

        // Now for all your render target views you must set the correct dimension type
        // based on if you use multisampling or not
        D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC drtv;
        dRtSwapChain.ViewDimension=sampleQuality==0?D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D:D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;

 // For depth stencil view
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC ddsv;
ddsv.ViewDimension=sampleQuality==0?D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D:D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
```

If you want to read a multisampled texture in your shader (if you render a fullscreen quad for example) you must declare the texture Texture2DMS<>.

Comment: He's going to use a D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC in Direct3D 10?

Comment: This is a much later reply, as I've been incredibly busy, but I really do appreciate the help.

I can't seem to get it to work (even changing D3D11 to D3D10), and I'm not sure why - do you have a have a depth stencil enabled for this? I'm not doing your usual 3D scene and NULL that out in the call to OMSetRenderTargets instead of just disabling the depth buffering.

Comment: Also, I've been a lurker for a long time and never posted until now, sorry I can't upvote your answer!

Comment: Two things:

Even though I have a new card, from GetMSAAQuality (or something like it), I never get anything better than count==8 and quality==0 (1, instead of 0, filled by CheckMultisampleLevels). Using the quality==0 check makes it so all the DESC members are not multisampled.

Aside from that (for now I'm doing a count==1 check instead of quality==0), what do I even do with the Texture2DMS<>? That was the part I was most confused on in the first place. How am I supposed to render from *and* to a texture at the same time? If I use ResolveSubresource, how do I present whatever texture I use?

Comment: So you have tried setting the count to 1,2,...8 but still nothing? Strange, which GPU do you have, and what DXGI_FORMAT do you use? To present you mean to display on the display? Just use the texture (render target) from the swap chain and render to it. Texture2DMS is used only if you read the multisampled texture in the shader.